# Flink Multiple Linear Regression: does it have Predict?

Tags: scala, linear-regression, apache-flink, flinkml

I've a multiple regression model trained and now I want to use it to predict.

Reading the [documents](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/libs/ml/multiple_linear_regression.html#predict) I understand that the input is a labeled vector and the output is a Dataset with tuple [*InputValue, PredictValue*], right?

I create my labeled Vector:

```
val mapped = data.map {x => new org.apache.flink.ml.common.LabeledVector (x._4, org.apache.flink.ml.math.DenseVector(x._1,x._2,x._3)) }

//Print
mapped: org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[org.apache.flink.ml.common.LabeledVector] = org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet@7d4fefdc
LabeledVector(6.7, DenseVector(33.0, -52.26, 28.3))
LabeledVector(5.8, DenseVector(36.0, 45.53, 150.93))
.....
```

And with my model created and trained I predict:

```
// Calculate the predictions for the test data
val predictions = mlr.predict(mapped)
```

I got this **ERROR**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no PredictOperation defined for org.apache.flink.ml.regression.MultipleLinearRegression which takes a DataSet[org.apache.flink.ml.common.LabeledVector] as input.
```

But you can see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/libs/ml/multiple_linear_regression.html#examples) that the official documentation say that it exits.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prediction of `LabeledVectors` has been removed with this [commit](https://github.com/tillrohrmann/flink/commit/7a7a294033ef99c596e59f670e2e4ae9262f5c5f). Unfortunately, the Flink documentation has not been updated. I've created an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6840) to update the documentation.

If you want to predict `LabeledVectors`, then you have to write your own `PredictOperation` which supports the respective types.

Comment: **Thanks for your help** Just to know.. Why did you decide to remove it? By the way, I think I found several mistakes more... what a pity, such a powerful tool with that documentation... If you need some young talent to fix it, I can help! ;)

Comment: How may I know the results of algorithm predictions? The residuals, mean square error, r², etc.

Comment: The Flink community always welcomes new contributors. So if you like to help, then create some JIRA issues and start cracking :-) The reason why we removed it was that it was a corner case added for the evaluation. Instead we wanted to develop a proper evaluation framework which allows you to calculate measures for your predictions. Exactly what you've asked for: mean square error, residuals, etc. Since the evaluation framework is not finished yet, you would have to implement on your own.

Comment: I will! :) although I'm afraid I don't have the enough level yet haha by the way, could you take a look to this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353875/trigger-execution-model-linearregression-in-flink-slower-than-spark) I've followed a answer you gave to someone but it doesn't work completly for me. I really appreciate if you could help in this post because it's for my thesis.

Comment: There is no reason to be afraid. Every contributor is valuable for the community.